# how to find out the constant in "Big theta" notation

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

i'm having an issue solving for "big theta" notation. i understand that big O denotes the worst case and big omega denotes the best case.I also know we have to find two constants c1 and c2 for the big theta notation.My question is how to find out the values of constant(c) in big theta.

Comment: There is no recipe. Just you skills in establishing lower and upper bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Theta bracketing for a given function, say

```
f(n) = Θ(g(n))
```

is equivalent to proving the limit

```
lim(n->∞) f(n) / g(n)
```

exists*.

You do this by an educated guess about the asymptotic behavior of the function `f`.

Then the theory of limits tells you that there exists some `N` for which

```
n > N => |f(n) / g(n) - C| < ε,
```

which can be written

```
n > N => C - ε < f(n) / g(n) < C + ε
```

or

```
n > N => C1.g(n) < f(n) < C2.g(n).
```

This is where the constants `C1` and `C2` are coming from. In fact, all of this is the practice of limit computation.

---

*Technically, lower and upper limits may differ and you will perform two different computations.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are referring to this definition, right?

[image]

Lets try that on example. We have two functions that we identified with this complexity

```
f(n)=2*n^2
g(n)=10*n^2
```

If you know a bit about the topic, you already see that both have same complexity `O(n^2)`. Now it is time to prove that `f(n) = Theta(g(n))` by filling the definition.

By definition we can choose any of those values `c1, c2, n0`, the main limitation is that `n0` is just "start" and the equation has to be applied also for all the `n` that are bigger then that.

If we just fill the values it will be: `0 <= c1*2*n^2 <= 10*n^2 <= c2*2*n^2`. Now you can just fill the values that suits. So we want to have left part low enough and right part big enough. So lets choose `c1=1` and `c2=100`, we get `0 <= 1*2*n^2 <= 10*n^2 <= 100*2*n^2` which is `0 <= 2*n^2 <= 10*n^2 <= 200*n^2`. And here you go, thats all that is needed. Because the equation is quite simple, its clearly visible that any `n` will suit starting from 1.

There can be more difficult equation where for given `c1` and `c2` it will be true for `n0` which is 1000 (which means for all `n` starting from 1000). Imagine the `g(n)=100+2*n^2` then we would get this `0 <= 2*n^2 + 100 <= 10*n^2 <= 200*n^2 + 10000` then if you just put `n=1` you will get `0 <= 2*1 + 100 <= 10*1 <= 200*1 + 10000` which is `0 <= 102 <= 10 <= 10200` which is clearly not true. But from certain `n0` this equation will be true, i.e. for `n=100` you will get `0 <= 2*10000 + 100 <= 10*10000 <= 200*10000 + 10000` which is true and is true for all `n > 100`

Homework: Try to do the same with `f(n)=n^2` and `g(n)=n^3`. You will see that no matter which `c1` or `c2` you choose there will be some `n` big enough that will break the equation.